# Variadic templates and type definition with 'using'

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, using, variadic-templates

I wrote a small `using` statement to have easy access to the types of a variadic template parameter pack.

```
template<size_t index, typename args...>
using get = std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<args...>>::type;
```

But compiling this with clang (3.5.0) or gcc (4.9.0) fails. Here is the error output of clang:

```
error: expected ',' or '>' in template-parameter-list template<size_t index, typename args...>
                                                                                          ^
```

Is the `using` statement not combinable with variadic templates? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: maybe `typename` after `=`? Because `::type` is dependent on the template parameters

Comment: I VTCd for typo because it's `typename... args`, not `typename args...`, but yeah, `typename` is required as well.

Comment: If you'd like the other half of the close vote, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: Also, you find the exact solution in the example of the documentation of `std::tuple_element` at cppreference.com: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element

Comment: The compiler output was not very helpful for the `typename... args` typo. So I was wondering about why this fails. But as it turns out I realy was "doing something wrong".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things are wrong in your code.

First, since the definition of `std::tuple_element<...>` depends on what `...` is, you need to tell the compiler that `::type` refers to a type name, hence you need `typename` in front of it.

Second, variadic template parameters have their ellipsis in between `typename` (or `class`) and the name of the pack, i.e. `typename ...args` instead of `typename args...`.

So the fixed code is then:

```
template<size_t index, typename ...args>
using get = typename std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<args...>>::type;
```

Answer (score 6):

The ellipsis for the parameter pack needs to be after the `typename` (or `class`) keyword. It goes after the parameter name when you expand the pack.

```
template<size_t index, typename... args>
//                             ^^^
using get = typename std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<args...>>::type;
//          ^^^^^^^^^
```

You're also missing the `typename` keyword which is needed when referring to a nested dependent type.